# Making custom input range in canvas using KonvaJs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

i need an input type range in canvas for some purposes, i need to use that to change my fontsize. I already make the shape and also drag able, but the circle controller go beyond the line.

Just preview the bin to see what i mean. [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xelede/edit?html,js,output)

i want to limit the draging area to the line only like the input range works.

This is the [documentation](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/drag_and_drop/Complex_Drag_and_Drop.html) of KonvaJs library.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, use an html input-range element placed inside the canvas with CSS. But if you must "do it yourself" you can limit the thumbs "X" axis dragging using KonvaJS's [`dragBoundFunc`](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/drag_and_drop/Simple_Drag_Bounds.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working, coded by **Lavrton**

[Source](http://jsbin.com/hubetef/1/edit?html,output)

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();

 var Track = new Konva.Line({
            x: 44,
            y: 55,
            points: [60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            stroke: '#BDC3C7',
            strokeWidth: 6,
            visible: true,
            name: 'TrackLine',
            lineCap: 'sqare',
            lineJoin: 'sqare'
          });

    var TrackBall = new Konva.Circle({
            x: 44,
            y: 55,
            stroke: '#D35400',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            name: 'TrackControl',
            radius: 8,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false,
            visible: true,
            dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
              console.log(pos.x, Math.min(44, pos.x))
            return {
                x: Math.min(104, Math.max(44, pos.x)),
                y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
                };
            }
     });

layer.add(Track);
layer.add(TrackBall);

stage.add(layer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.10.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container" class="CanCont"></div>
```